Why does the *leverage* of an open-ended option change over time (and so quickly)?
I wonder how the leverage (not the price) of an option changes over time and why so quickly?
Naively speaking, I think of an option as the possibility to buy a stock at a certain price. If an option has a leverage of 5, I assume, I simply have the possibility to buy 5 stocks of the underlying at a certain price. So if I execute the option, I make money as follows:

win = 5 x (cur_price - buy_price).

As a concrete example, 2 days ago, I went short on Tesla, because I figured the debate about Musk's pay package should lead to a lower price.
I bought this option from Unicredit:

Stock price at the time: ca. 190$
Leverage ca. 10
Strike price: ca. 205$
No expiration date (I've heard this is mostly the case for European options)

Luckily, Tesla's stock price declined by 5% and the option's price rose by ca. 48%.
Now looking at it today, the leverage as shown on the option product page is only 6.46.
My questions are:

Why did the leverage change at all?
Why did the leverage fall by 30% in only 2 days?
How can I invest in a stock for say a year with a constant leverage?

I would be grateful for an intuition as well as math.
Thanks for your help!

You really shouldn't buy such a product if you have no idea what it is and how it works, especially if the KID states it's the highest level of risk. This is not a simple option. It's even with a daily resetting knockout (if I read the German term sheet properly), meaning if the knockout barrier is hit, you lose all your capital.

Leverage for a vanilla option is delta * stock price /option price, as explained here. As you can see, your idea of leverage with options is quite wrong.

Leverage in this particular security you reference is computed as price underlying * subscription ratio /price of turbo (Hebel = Kurs des Basiswerts x Bezugsverhältnis / Preis des Turbo). The closer the price of the underlying to the price of the turbo, the bigger the leverage (and the more likely the knockout).

You cannot invest in an underlying for a year with a fixed, say 10x leverage (unless you rebalance all the time). Any leverage requires derivatives. If you Google constant leverage you will find lots of results but they should all be on a daily basis. You can see here what this really means.



Thanks for the very helpful answers.
I think it should say "The closer the price of the underlying to the price of the turbo, the smaller the leverage (and the less likely the knockout)." right?
